# No HDMI audio on Linux Mint 19.1 with kernel 4.4

Tags: linux-mint, audio, hdmi

I work with Linux Mint 19.1 installed on thin clients. But I had a problem with the kernel 4.15 (VoIP connected on an Ethernet port doesn't work correctly) so I  changed the kernel to 4.4 to solve that. When I changed the kernel, the HDMI audio fails. I tried many things to fix this, but I could not.

I installed [pavucontrol](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/pavucontrol.1.html) on the PC, then noticed something weird. 
With the 4.15 kernel, the status port is plugged in, but with kernel 4.4, the status port is unplugged. Details follow below:

[Kernel 4.15](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wub5QE-bNas6l3fODIKAd88AnjQ39tLm/view?usp=sharing)

[Kernel 4.4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qnJe6tq9NVJX3RO9f6Dse1hkxApG0NKP/view?usp=sharing)

pacmd list-sinks with
Kernel 4.4:

```
pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_0e.0.hdmi-stereo>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
        state: SUSPENDED
        suspend cause: IDLE
        priority: 9030
        volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
                balance 0,00
        base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: no
        current latency: 0,00 ms
        max request: 0 KiB
        max rewind: 0 KiB
        monitor source: 0
        sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stereo
        used by: 0
        linked by: 0
        configured latency: 0,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 371,52 ms
        card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_0e.0>
        module: 7
        properties:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = "HDMI 0"
                alsa.id = "HDMI 0"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "3"
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x91410000 irq 129"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:0e.0"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sound/card0"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "8086"
                device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
                device.product.id = "5a98"
                device.product.name = "Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster"
                device.form_factor = "internal"
                device.string = "hdmi:0"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
                device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
                device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo"
                device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
                device.description = "Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
                alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC283"
                alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0283,1019983e,00100003 HDA:8086280a,80860101,00100000"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        ports:
                hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        active port: <hdmi-output-0>
```

Pacmd List-cards

```
pacmd list-cards
1 card(s) available.
    index: 0
        name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_0e.0>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        owner module: 7
        properties:
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x91410000 irq 129"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:0e.0"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sound/card0"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "8086"
                device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
                device.product.id = "5a98"
                device.product.name = "Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster"
                device.form_factor = "internal"
                device.string = "0"
                device.description = "Built-in Audio"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        profiles:
                input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 60, available: unknown)
                output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6000, available: no)
                output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6060, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5460, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 360, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 360, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5260, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5260, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
                off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
        active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
        sinks:
                alsa_output.pci-0000_00_0e.0.hdmi-stereo/#0: Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
        sources:
                alsa_output.pci-0000_00_0e.0.hdmi-stereo.monitor/#0: Monitor of Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
                alsa_input.pci-0000_00_0e.0.analog-stereo/#1: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
        ports:
                analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (priority 8900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
                hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

My hardware config:

```
lspci -v

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Host Bridge (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Host Bridge
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0


00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5a85 (rev 0b) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device 9cc7
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Kernel modules: i915


00:0e.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster (rev 0b) (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 129
    Memory at 91410000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 91000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel


00:0f.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Trusted Execution Engine
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    Memory at 9141f000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [a4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me


00:12.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SATA AHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Memory at 91414000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at 9141c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at 9141b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci


00:13.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series PCI Express Port A #1 (rev fb) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 120
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: 91300000-913fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series PCI Express Port A
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] #00
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] #00
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp


00:13.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series PCI Express Port A #2 (rev fb) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 121
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: 91200000-912fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series PCI Express Port A
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] #00
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] #00
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp


00:13.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series PCI Express Port A #3 (rev fb) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: 91100000-911fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series PCI Express Port A
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] #00
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] #00
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp


00:15.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series USB xHCI (rev 0b) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series USB xHCI
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Memory at 91400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd


00:1a.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series PWM Pin Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series PWM Pin Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at 9141a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 91419000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pwm-lpss
    Kernel modules: pwm_lpss_pci


00:1c.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series eMMC Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series eMMC Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 39
    Memory at 91418000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 91417000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci


00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Low Pin Count Interface (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Low Pin Count Interface
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0


00:1f.1 SMBus: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SMBus Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at 91416000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801


01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at 91304000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 91300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169


02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3165
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 128
    Memory at 91200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number ac-ed-5c-ff-ff-fc-b9-df
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi


03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
    I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
    Memory at 91104000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 91100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Is it possible to use the HDMI Audio without an update to the kernel?